# Anti XSS PHP Library (Class 'voku\\helper\\AntiXSS')

Tags: php, xss

I've been trying to use this Anti XSS Library: https://github.com/voku/anti-xss/blob/master/README.md
But I'm getting following error:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Class 'voku\\helper\\AntiXSS' not found in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/xss.php on line 6\n'
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
use voku\helper\AntiXSS;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$antiXss = new AntiXSS();

$harm_string = "Hello, i try to <script>alert('Hack');</script> your site";
echo $antiXss->xss_clean($harm_string);



?>
```

Comment: Did you ran `composer req voku/anti-xss` or `composer update` or `composer install`?

Comment: No, i just copied and pasted the code...

Comment: So you definitely should install this lib by `composer req voku/anti-xss`. More [about composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and [require](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md).

Comment: I ran composer req voku/anti-xss command in terminal, It installed and everything went OK. But still getting same error :(

Comment: Just to be sure: 1. Is `xss.php` file in the same dir as `vendor` dir? 2. Does ` composer info voku/anti-xss` shows info about package?

Comment: Issue resolved. Thanks for your help. I've isntalled composer req voku/anti-xss on directory where domain root files were available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to require the autoload before you reference the class.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use voku\helper\AntiXSS;
```

Otherwise, this dependancy namespace will not be loaded into memory in the context, as it is loaded inside the autoload.php file. This is why it says class not found.

Also Make Sure You've Installed via "composer require"

```
composer require voku/anti-xss
```

Comment: Why do you think it would make a difference?

Comment: I have ammended the answer to give further clarification.

Comment: From [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#114265): "The `<?php use ?>` statement does not load the class file. You have to do this with the `<?php require ?>` statement or by using an autoload function."

Comment: Ok, I changed use to require voku\helper\AntiXSS; and in Logs im getting: AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Undefined constant 'voku\\helper\\AntiXSS'

Comment: Maxime, that is what the require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; does. IT loads the class into memory.

Mememe, change it back to a use statement. Further, the autoload.php file should not be blank. You should research how to use Composer or a similar package manager which will install the dependancy into the project for you.

Comment: The class is not loaded until it is used. Requiring `autoload.php` just registers an autoloading function which, *when called*, loads the class into memory. Using actually the class calls the function with appropriate values.

Comment: And none of that will happen if you have your use statement before you actually require your autoloader. Are you here to help Mememe or are you here to discuss semantics?  

I said the namespace is loaded in my edit which would clearly suggest I understand the premise of the autoloader, and when I said it loads the class I meant classpath.

Comment: The [`use`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) statement is just to not use the fully qualified name of class (voku\helper\AntiXSS). One could remove entirely the `use` statement and do `$antiXss = new voku\helper\AntiXSS();`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your help and i resolved the issue, the installation of Installing voku/anti-xss  was malfunctioned. I've re-installed it and it's working fine now